# xmlsoccer.com to sql

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, xml

I'm trying to parse XML from `xmlsoccer.com.

Using this example http://xmlsoccer.wikia.com/wiki/.NET_code_example:_Livescore_website

I created SQL tables and made no mistakes. I copied whole code, but this code is only for full access users but I'm using DEMO service.

```
private XDocument GetLiveScoreDocument()
{
    XMLSoccerCOM.FootballDataSoapClient serviceClient = new XMLSoccerCOM.FootballDataSoapClient();
    var node = serviceClient.GetLiveScore(apiKey);
    XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument();
    xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(new XmlNodeReader(node));
    return xmlDoc;
}
```

I changed `FootballDataSoapClient` to `FootballDataDemoSoapClient` and run web site

```
XMLSoccerCOM.FootballDataDemoSoapClient serviceClient = new XMLSoccerCOM.FootballDataDemoSoapClient();
    var node = serviceClient.GetLiveScore("My Api");
    XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument();
    xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(new XmlNodeReader(node));
    return xmlDoc;
```

program throws exception

> An endpoint configuration section for contract 'XMLSoccerCOM.FootballDataDemoSoap' could not be loaded because more than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found. Please indicate the preferred endpoint configuration section by name.

I don't know how to fix it. Please help me if you have experience to parsing scores from `xmlscore.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the service reference for this web service, it creates two possible bindings to use. For example, when I tried it, in my app.config I get this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="FootballDataDemoSoap" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="FootballDataDemoSoap12">
                <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
                <httpTransport />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://www.xmlsoccer.com/FootballDataDemo.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="FootballDataDemoSoap"
            contract="ServiceReference1.FootballDataDemoSoap" name="FootballDataDemoSoap" />
        <endpoint address="http://www.xmlsoccer.com/FootballDataDemo.asmx"
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="FootballDataDemoSoap12"
            contract="ServiceReference1.FootballDataDemoSoap" name="FootballDataDemoSoap12" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

So, there are two possible bindings to choose from. The difference between them, is that one is configured to use Soap1.2, while the other is using Soap1.1. More on that here http://www.w3.org/2003/06/soap11-soap12.html, but presumably both will work.

Then the error makes perfect sense - it has found more than one possible configuration to use, so it doesn't know which one to take. You need to tell it. You can do this by using the constructor overload that takes the binding configuration name. For example, either:

```
FootballDataDemoSoapClient client = new FootballDataDemoSoapClient("FootballDataDemoSoap");
```

or

```
FootballDataDemoSoapClient client = new FootballDataDemoSoapClient("FootballDataDemoSoap12");`
```